# Variable i cannot be read at compile time

Tags: d

I have this code:

```
class Set(T){
    private T[] values;

    T get(uint i){
        return ((i < values.length) ? T[i] : null);
    }
...
```

And when I try use this class this way:

```
set.Set!(int) A;
```

compiler gives error at the `return` line: `set.d|9|error: variable i cannot be read at compile time`

Can somebody explain, what's wrong in my code? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that's all the code?

Comment: ooh othugh the `T[i]` line is wrong anyway, T is a type, the array is `values`

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `values[i]`?

Comment: Yes, I meant values[i], Thanks!

Comment: does that fix it? if so you can post it as an answer or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the answer: the code simply referenced the wrong variable. The reason it gave the error it did is that T[i] is trying to get an index out of a compile-time list of types... which needs i to be available at compile time too. However, since i is a regular variable, it isn't. (You can have compile time variables btw - the result of a function may be CT evaled, or the index on a foreach over a static list, or an enum value.) However, what was wanted here was a runtime index into the array... so the values is the right symbol since it is the data instead of the type.

By Adam D. Ruppe

Comment: That is the answer: the code simply referenced the wrong variable. The reason it gave the error it did is that `T[i]` is trying to get an index out of a compile-time list of types... which needs `i` to be available at compile time too. However, since `i` is a regular variable, it isn't. (You can have compile time variables btw - the result of a function may be CT evaled, or the index on a foreach over a static list, or an `enum` value.) However, what was wanted here was a runtime index into the array... so the `values` is the right symbol since it is the data instead of the type.

Comment: That's a truly terrible error message for this particular mistake. Do you have any opinions on whether we can/should special-case this in the compiler @AdamD.Ruppe?

Comment: eh maybe but it would be hard to tell if it was an intentional subscript or not.... well, actually, T here isn't even valid to subscript anyway, so it should probably be a type error with no special casing needed. But if it was `T...` then this error would probably be right.